# Test in emulator is ok, but it can not on phone

Tags: android, emulation

I test in emulator it can run correctly. But I test on the phone, it always throw an exception.

```
  public static String doGet(String url) {
    try {
      HttpGet method = new HttpGet(url); 
      DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
 //     HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("10.0.0.172", 80);  The two sentence added on the phone, it still can not run
   //   client.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY, proxy); 
      method.setHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
      HttpResponse response = client.execute(method);
      int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
      if (status != HttpStatus.SC_OK)
        throw new Exception("");
      return EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      return "Connection errors！";
    }
  }
```

I check API4 when create project. And test in emulator android 1.6. Test the phone is on android 2.3.3. I also test in computer android-x86 2.2 jars. It is no problem. I add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` in `AndroidManifest.xml`. I do not know the reason. Anyone’s opinion is thankful.

Comment: post your logcat output

Comment: did you check that your phone is connected to internet ?

Answer (score 0):

What thread you call this function? You cant create connection in UI thread

Comment: 2.2+ versions in Android requires to call network connection in threads or async-task and following that will solve the problem I guess as mentioned by Trần Sĩ Long